# Skip a scenario from a story when running my test cases

Tags: maven, jbehave

I have my scenario like this:

```
Scenario: Search a something
Meta:
@ID TC_SCH_Search_001
@module Search
@author tSanchez
@type functional
Given Open search application in Normal mode
When I select Search on Main Menu
And video filter is selected
And Look for rocky
And Press OK
Then Search results are displayed
```

**Question:** How can skip a scenario from a story when running my test cases in jbehave?
I have tried adding @skip or +skip to the metadata but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the skip under 'Meta'
For example:

```
Scenario: ID 6950 - Scenario 5. - blah blah
Meta:
@skip
When aaa
Then bbb
```

Comment: Adding the skip metadata is not making my scenario to be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Not Only add the @Skip under 'Meta'
Meta:
@skip

You also should add the '-skip' in the "Meta.filters"

Hope this help you